# feathers js: how to validate access token

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

So after authenticating I get an access token in which I store in browser session. My question is, in case user refreshes, how do I validate the token?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out just use /authentication AND use jwt strategy:

https://dove.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/jwt.html